# How can I keep my Ruby Gems the same on several servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I have several servers for development, staging, testing and production and want to keep my Ruby version and Gem versions in sync between the different machines -- what's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you use bundler, you can specify the versions in a Gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3, you can just use the Gemfile, and bundler, and when you do a "bundle update" on whatever machine you're on, it will automatically install the correct versions of Gems for that user account.

You should use RVM to manage your Ruby versions and to keep the Gems for different Ruby versions separate from each other.

You should also create a "gemset" for your Rails application, to make sure that the Gems installed there are not modified from another Rails application you might use or develop on the same machine.

http://beginrescueend.com/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

Comment: Good advice. Note that you can easily use Bundler/Gemfiles even if you're not using Rails 3. Furthermore, I personally recommend using Bundler's `--path` instead of gemsets; [this article](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/) explains more, but gemsets are certainly an alternative..

Answer (score 2):

rvm is the best option to manage ruby versions

However I am not sure if you really want to change ruby version often.

bundler & Gemfile is great way to handle gem versions

Track you Gemfile && Gemfile.lock files in git(or other cvs) tree, and run bundle install on change

Comment: ah! i was just about to post the same answer. +1 for rvm, there is a feature called [named gemsets](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) that allows you to pack your gems.

Answer (score 1):

You can also, in the event you have more gems in a gemset than just what's in your Gemfile, do a

```
rvm gemset export gemsetname.gems
```

And then on the other machine you would do a

```
rvm gemset import gemsetname.gems
```

You can even do it as

```
rvm x.x.x@mygemset exec rvm gemset export mygemset.gems
```

so you don't have to go directly into your gemset. And then on the new machine,

```
rvm --create use x.x.x@mygemset && rvm gemset import mygemset.gems
```

which will create and then populate your mygemset gem set.